# The ROLLBACK statement has no effect on the values of host variables or on the flow of control?

Tags: oracle

I tried to test, but no good result;

As far as I got, when i use variables from other packages and use rollback, it does not have any effect on it. but when i test it, it is not working as expected

```
declare
begin
  for i in 1 .. 10
  loop
    begin
      otherPackage.temp :=10;      
      People.Insert_One(i_Id => v_Arr(i));
    end;    
    end loop;    
    rollback;
    dbms_output.put_line(otherPackage.temp);
end;
```

otherPackage.temp is default -1, when i used in this test window, and used rollback, it shows 10, the changed value;

Answer (score 4):

You have used the variable `temp` of the package `otherPackage` only once in the logic to assign the value 10 to it.

`ROLLBACK` only removes the effect of any `DML`. `PL/SQL` variables do not have any effect of `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`.

Hence, you are getting 10 as the value of `temp` when you are printing it, the same value which you have assigned it in the same session.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is a concept that was not clear to me many years ago when I was first coding in PL/SQL. I wish someone had explained to me that programming in PL/SQL is pretty much just like programming in Java or VB or any other language: your code is connecting to a database and having the database do work on its behalf. The actual database activity is separate from the procedural code. The database transaction scope does not include PL/SQL package variables. The reason this gets confusing is because PL/SQL is embedded in the database.